# Ubunty 14.04 freezes when I select a big chunk of text in LibreOffice

Tags: drivers, nvidia, freeze

When I start selecting text (size of more then a paragraph) in LibreOffice, the entire system freezes.

If I use the mouse and left click or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the system freezes so I cannot finish selecting.

If I use LibreOffice's menu command <kbd>Select all</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> no freeze happens. As a workaround, I switched to Google Docs until I can use LibreOffice.

These are my laptop details:

- Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 540 @ 2.53GHz × 4
- Gallium 0.4 on NVA8 32-bit
- ram 488,0 GB
- VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
- Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T410
- Kernel driver in use: nouveau
- Memory: total 3,8G used 3,3G free 556M shared 226M buffers 66M cached 562M -/+ buffer: 2,7G 1,2G
  Swap:         3,9G       1,1G       2,7G

Ubuntu newly installed, only one OS, I deleted Windows to install Ubuntu.

Comment: maybe problem with memory. Run `memtest86`

Comment: Try this: In Acrobat Reader -- choose File -- Save As or File -- Save As Other -- Text.  In Libreoffice Writer -- choose File -- Open -- File.txt.

Comment: i think the problem is not with Acrobat. I removed Libre Office and intalled Open office - same issue even if Acrobat is closed. IF  copy big chank of text laptop freezes. If I copy slamm parts no freez happened. But this is stil very inconvenient forsing to go back to Windows.

Comment: There are a few unclear yet important facts missing from your question. I assume you want to copy text through the clipboard. Which application is the source, which is the destination. How do you copy and paste the text – Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, middle click with the mouse, a menu action? At which point exactly does your system freeze? Which parts freeze – just either or both applications, the whole desktop session, the whole system (verify with a switch to a virtual terminal (e. g. with Ctrl+Alt+F1))? Could you please clear those up?

Comment: thanks, David, for your questions. I address them one by one

Comment: the source - LIBREOFFICE, DESTINATION DOES NOT MATTER. WHENEVER I COPY MORE OR LESS LONG TEXT (LONGER THEN ONE PARAGRAPH) FROM LIBREOFFICE FILE LAPTOP IMMEDIATELY FREESES.. I USE MOUSE. At which point exactly does your system freeze? - AS SOON AS I HIGHLIGHT BIG ENOUGH CHANK OF TEXT, SOMETIME IT FREEZES SO THAT I CANNOT FINISH HIGHLIGHTING ENOUGH TEXT WHICH I WANTED TO HIGHLIGHT. Which parts freeze – just either or both applications, the whole desktop session, the whole system  - ENTIRE SYSTEM, I CANNOT MOVE ANYTHING BUT MOUSE COURSOR, EVEN THIS MOVES SLOWLY ORCOPLETELY FREEZES TOO.

Comment: system freeze if  I highlight by using mouse, or CTRL+C+down. If I use LibreOffice menu comand Highligh all or CNTR+A - no freeze happens.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add the output of `free --human`.  Please [edit] your answer to reflect this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the video driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

and reboot.

I am suggesting 304, because I know that it works better that 340 on that card.

Comment: Pilot6, it looks like  sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 solved the issue with freezing.

Comment: @AntonBurkov Please accept the question to show other people that the solution works. It can be done by clicking the check sign at the left.

Comment: Nice, Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing. First using LibreOffice, which i uninstalled. Then after installing Openoffice. Selecting a piece of text in order to copy it everything froze. 
My problem was solved by turning off "Transparency" which can be found in  "Tools-Options-View". Clearly a graphical issue indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I first tried deselecting transparency in Libre Office, that worked.  I then turned transparency back on and updated the driver per the answer above and that worked also.  Some of my details are:

```
albert@dv4-1412:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce G 105M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30f7
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau


albert@dv4-1412:~$ free --human
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.0G       746M       1.2G       5.6M        53M       330M
-/+ buffers/cache:       362M       1.6G
Swap:         2.0G         0B       2.0G
```